# How to navigate to a route with query param but without showing ? and = in the URL

Tags: angular

I've never implemented routing in Angular. my requirement is to navigate to a details page when an icon is clicked from parent component. Here is my code:

**product.component.ts**

```
  // method called when the corresponding pencil/edit icon is clicked
  loadSingleRecord() {
    this._router.navigate(['products/electronic/billing/'], {
      queryParams: { id: 12 }, // let it be id 12 for sometime
    });
  }
```

**product-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: 'electronic/billing/:id',
    component: BillingSingleRecordComponent,
  },
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes), HttpClientModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ProductsRoutingModule {}
```

This logic is working fine:

> localhost:4205/products/electronic/billing/record?id=29

but I dont want to show `?id=29`. Can it be simple like this: `localhost:4205/products/electronic/billing/record/29`. Please help.

I forgot to meantion that on reaching the details component I want the id also:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      console.log(id); // OUTPUT undefined
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:id` in the path `electronic/billing/:id` is not a queryParam, but rather a route parameter (also known as path variable). Check out [this tutorial](https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/routeparams) for more info

When you navigate, you should use

```
this._router.navigate(['products/electronic/billing', id]);
```

if you want to read this in your component, you can use

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
        let id = params['id'];
        console.log(id);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i need to get that id in the details component. I've added a new portion to the question. Can you please help.

Comment: accepting this answer because it solved my question and it provided a tutorial link for further study.